# Get Database table resultset on my swt Table

Tags: java, jdbc, swt

I am new to SWT and I need to use it's table widget. I would like to Right send queries to my database and a table is created. The `setText()` function only takes a new array of strings or a String, How what should I do in order for my rows to be displayed despite the number of columns. This is my code:

```
try{

ResultSet getTable=dbconnect.connect.createStatement().executeQuery("select * from Status");
ResultSetMetaData md = getTable.getMetaData();
int columns = md.getColumnCount();
for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
tblclmnNewColumn = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
tblclmnNewColumn.setWidth(100);
tblclmnNewColumn.setText(md.getColumnName(i));
columnNames.add( md.getColumnName(i));

}

for(int i=0;i<columnNames.size();i++){
String set;
if(i==columnNames.size()-1){
set="getTable.getString"+"("+'"'+columnNames.get(i)+'"'+")";
}else{                  
set="getTable.getString"+"("+'"'+columnNames.get(i)+'"'+")"+",";
                    }
columsresultset.add(set);
element[i]=columsresultset.get(i);

System.out.println(columsresultset.get(i)); 
                }
String elements[]=new String[columsresultset.size()];
while (getTable.next()) {
TableItem tableItem =(TableItem) new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
tableItem.setText(elements);                         
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? I don't really understand...

Answer (score 1):

How about using `setText(yourDatabaseColumnIndex - 1, yourDatabaseColumnValue)`. Of course you have to create your `TableColumn`s anyway, just as you did in your code. Example:

```
while(resultSet.next())
{
    TableItem tableItem = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
    for(int i = 1; i <= resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++)
    {
        tableItem.setText(i-1, resultSet.getString(i));
    }
}
```

No guarantees that I didn't miss any `;` or `{` or something `;-)`. Also you could optimize this a little by writing the column count to a variable.